# Fleet GPS tracking solution with real time location of vehicles with route history

Tags: gps

Looking for a recommendation for a web based Fleet GPS Tracking solution to track vehicles and dispatch to drivers using an app, I Prefer tracking the vehicles rather than tracking phones, any suggestion?

Comment: Operating system (or web based)?  Budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a solution from [www.Highpointgps.com](http://www.Highpointgps.com), it uses [tracking devices](http://www.highpointgps.com/gps-tracking-devices.html) installed in the vehicles to track the vehicles on a map online, the movement history playback is available online for 2 years, Also has a feature to dispatch to a Garmin GPS or android app, and to record the Hours of service as E-LogBook compliant solution.

[image]
Interface is very user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled GPS vehicle tracking and found [this](http://www.spireon.com/gps-vehicle-tracking/). Looks to have the technology that you requested and more. It's a cloud-based software that connects with your phone and any other device (laptop, desktop, tablet, etc). It uses a tracking device that is installed onto the vehicle so you will be tracking the vehicle and not the phone. Not sure about pricing though. Good luck with your search.

Comment: I believe it's Spireon GPS vehicle tracking, and you can certainly find more information here: http://www.spireon.com/gps-vehicle-tracking/